# Dojo Toolkit DOM attributes

Tags: html, dom, dojo

This might be a really stupid question, and if so, I apologize.  I am relatively new to the web development world and am just getting my feet wet with AJAX, specifically with the Dojo Toolkit.

Here's my question -- is there a comprehensive list of Dojo HTML attributes (e.g. dojoType, etc.)?  I am having difficulty finding what attributes are available to specific DOM elements when using Dojo.  I have scoured the Dojo documentation and API's, but not much luck.  Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you' re wrong about "dojoType" property.

Dojo doesn't have a list of attributes to use on HTML node, dojoType is a special word used to define which nodes would be a widget.

This is a link additional info about the dojo parser.

I hope this help you.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/parser.html

Answer (score 0):

To inspect attributes of almost whatever object you want, just install firebug in you browser and in your code, make this:

console.dir( objetThatYouWantToInspectAttribuitesFor );